# Hard disk format count

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

Is there any way to find whether you have formatted your internal hard disk. Does any OEM apply such capability in the BIOS? I have an HP ProBook, does it have the capability?

Comment: You seem to have a mistaken idea about disc formatting.  There are high-level formatting, low-level formatting, and partitioning, which are all quite different operations.  You need to clarify which you are actually asking about, because you're mixing them all up.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit difficult to see what you are asking as your headline and question appear to ask different questions.  In summary you can easily tell if a drive is formatted, but can't tell how many times its been formatted with any certainty.

Whether a drive has been formatted or not would not really be up to the BIOS, it would be stored in SMART information on the drive itself.  Unfortunately there are lots of different ways to format a drive, and this is done at the Operating system level rather then as an instruction to BIOS or disk [ I'm assuming you are talking about a regular format which can be run by an average user], so not something the drive or BIOS would interact with.

SMART won't tell you how many times a drive has been formatted but might give some clues about usage which might let you infer some information - exactly what will depend on the type of drive, and this is certainly not a good way of going about things (unless you are looking into the health of the drive).

If you are simply looking if your drive is formatted, just put it in a system and if the partitions are accessible its formatted.

Comment: suppose if a drive was formatted in fat32 or ext4 and someone reformatted it in ntfs and then in again fat/ext4, can i find it out?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  Conceivably yes, but it would require very advanced expertise and an understanding of the layout specifics of NTFS which I don't really have.

Comment: you could scan the disk for things which might be relevant to an NTFS filesystem in a place where FAT32 or EXT4 does not overwrite - for example the duplicate copy of the NTFS boot sector which will be located in the middle or at the end of the volume - if you have mad skills and a hex editor).  Of-course if the disk was overwritten with 0's between formats you can't tell. Never done it, but conceptually grepping for the string "A kernel file is too discontiguous" throughout the whole disk might [or might not ] indicate that the disk has been formatted to NTFS.